# how to send vars to php code in actionscript

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I need to send a variable to php server and write it into a text file, my php code works just fine it creates a file and save it. but I flash doesnt seem to connect with the server

heres my action script that I used

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.sendToURL;
    public class SendToPhp extends MovieClip
    {
        private var stringy:String = "Im doing this!";
        //private var vote:int = 1;
        public function SendToPhp()
        {
            trace("hi");
            var requestt:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://phphost.web44.net/tsty.php?stringy="+stringy);
            sendToURL(requestt);
        }
    }
}
```

the code runs with no errors; it just open a blank flash and trace "hi"

my php code(which works just fine):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
          <?php
            $stringy = $_REQUEST['stringy'];
            $file = "data.txt";

            $fp = fopen($file, "a") or die("Couldn't open $file for login!");
            fwrite($fp, $stringy) or die("Couldn't open new page!");

            fclose($fp);
            echo "Proceed to newly open page.";
            ?>
        </p>   
    </body>
</html>
```

and also I want the php code to process the data I send him through flash without opening a web page

please anyone know what could be wrong?
and also how can I know if flash is connecting correctly?

Comment: you will know if it is connecting because it will write to your file ... you can test your php by just going to the url with a query string

Comment: I uploaded the file to a web page, and it worked fine!, I dont know whats the problem, but my preview cannot connect with the server,,,

Comment: done any basic debugging, e.g. `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see what's actually coming to the server?

Comment: your not uploading a file ... you are submitting a string

Comment: I meant I uploaded the .swf file on gamejolt.com then it works, when I use test (ctrl+enter) in flash it does nothing, if I open the swf from a folder it shows this :

SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file file:///C|/Users/Big%20Boss/Desktop/استيراد%20الخرا/php/php%20test.swf cannot access Internet URL http://phphost.web44.net/tsty.php?stringy=Im doing this!.
 at global/flash.net::sendToURL()
 at SendToPhp()
 at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
 at flash.display::Sprite()
 at flash.display::MovieClip()

Comment: Make sure your security publish settings are correct in flash ('use network only', instead of 'use local only').  Use a `Loader` object instead of `SendToURL`